# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ifconsol.lib'

Tags: c++, fortran

I am trying to compile an open source project OpenSees https://github.com/OpenSees/OpenSees for structural engineers. The program is written in C++, uses libraries written in Fortran, and runs through TCL. I am using Visual Studio 19 for building the solution. The problem is that I get the following message

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ifconsol.lib'
```

I have unloaded the project and deleted any reference to 'ifconsol.lib', reloaded, and then rebuilt the solution but the problem persists.

Comment: Is https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/Error-LNK1104-Cannot-open-file-ifconsol-lib/td-p/820786 of any use?

Comment: Thanks. I've found the fortran file directory and included it in the library directories